# Where does this equation come from? $ \frac{1}{2}mv^{2\:}=\:qV $

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

We assume that a mass spectrometer has an accelerating voltage.
At first I have to calculate the speed at which the particle moves, then by the energy conservation law:

$$\ K_0 + U_o = K + U $$

At the begining I understand that $$\ U_0 = 0 $$
but I don't know why at the end  $$\ K = 0 $$

K = Kinetic energy

U = potential energy

m = mass

v = velocity

q = charge or the particule

V = voltage

Comment: You need to give us the context of your problem. What $m$, $v$, $q$ and $V$ is, where did you see the equation, and where exactly are you stuck at deriving it. Otherwise, it is too broad a question to receive a proper answer

Comment: Related Post by OP :-https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544422/how-do-i-get-this-frac12mv2-qv

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this arises from equating kinetic energy to electric potential energy. Respectively the formulas are,

$$K=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$ where $m$ is mass and $v$ is velocity.
$$U=qV$$ where $q$ is charge and $V$ is the electric potential.